# How to avoid Internet Explorer's “Webpage has expired” when using the back button in classic asp page?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp-classic

I am using IE11 browser and for the below line of code getting webpage expired error message .

```
Response.Write "<input type=button onClick='history.go(-1);' value='Back'>This is valid"
Response.End
```

When click on back button showing webpage expired error message.please let me know how to resolve this issue in classic asp page.

Comment: See if this helps: https://forums.asp.net/post/4260895.aspx

Comment: how to add cache control in classic asp page header?

Comment: Please help me to provide possible solution for this issue.i am trying from long time but could not able to find the solution .

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this might be setting `Response.CacheControl` to `Public`, as stated in this solution from Microsoft: https://forums.asp.net/post/4260895.aspx

This can be added to the page like this:

```
<% 
  Response.CacheControl = "Public" 
%> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        Lorem ipsum...
    </body> 
</html>
```

I would also suggest reading the documentation on the `CacheControl` property available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524721(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us about the context of the previous page, but FYI, this warning can occur on many browsers if the last page was the result of a form POST.

To avoid issues like that, you should avoid loading a new page as a direct result of a POST, and instead, redirect the user to a new page using `Response.Redirect` (which will result in a GET). You lose the advantage of having your variables at hand, but you can potentially save them to the session or URL parameters if they are needed.